# Information content for one event

Tags: information-theory

I have event that has probability $p=0.96$. There is such task:

*How many an information I need to determinate the event that has probability $q=0.04$?*

**Anyway:**
*How many bits I need to deteminate the event?*

We must use a formula of information content: $I=-{log}_{2}q=-{log}_{2}0.04=4.64$ bits. **How should we explain it that we need about 5 bits?** I'm going to build a follow tree as below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5rHZ.png)

**I presume**, that 5 bits is necessary, because 1 bit determinates symbol that has probability $P=0.5$. I want to say if two events have equal probabilities that 1 bit is enough for us. But in the task first four bits are "inclined" to event with $p=0.96$ and we should balance events by adding new fivest bit. **Is that right?**

Comment: "How many an information I need to determinate the event that has probability..." Sorry, that's impossible to understand.

Comment: What particular?

Comment: The whole sentene makes no sense to me.